# tf.function with input signature errors out when calling a sub layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

The following works just fine

```py
class MyModel(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(name='MyModel')
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(50)

    @tf.function
    def __call__(self, inputs):
        return self.dense(inputs)

my_model = MyModel()
my_model(tf.ones((4, 42, 30, 200), name='features'))
```

However, when I try to explicitly specify the input signature in the `tf.function` decorator the code fails:

```py
class MyModel(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(name='MyModel')
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(50)

    @tf.function(input_signature=[
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, None, None), dtype=tf.float32)
    ])
    def __call__(self, inputs):
        return self.dense(inputs)

my_model = MyModel()
my_model(tf.ones((4, 42, 30, 200), name='features'))
```

Leads to the following error:

```
ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Your `tf.Module` is creating inside a `tf.keras.Model`; a Keras model has two different phases:

1. The model construction, where each layer is defined given the input shape
2. The model execution, where the built model is used to run the forward pass.

When you specify the input shape of the first layer of your model (using the `input_shape` attribute of `Dense` or the `tf.keras.layers.Input` layer), Keras is able to execute the first phase, model construction, because it now knows that the first weight matrix should be something like `input_shape[-1] * <number_units>` (50 in your case).

When you, instead, **do not** specify the input shape, what happens is that Keras **can't** execute  the model construction on the model definition time, but it has to wait until the first input is passed to the model; this input has a defined shape (`(4, 42, 30, 200)` in your case) and thus it can runs the model construction and execution in a row.

All this happens when you are not specifying a shape.

But in your second example, you're specifying an input shape of the `__call__` method of your `tf.Module` that is propagated to the `__call__` of your `tf.keras.Model`.

Thus, what happens here is that you're asking the Keras model to do the model construction and execution in a row, but since there are no defines shapes (since you're passing `(None, None, None, None)` and thus `input_shape[-1] is None`) Keras just can't define the model.

Comment: I want to keep the signature in the annotation because for serialization purposes. How can I do this while getting rid of the error?